# Update Panel content after a click on a widget of a Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My add-on needs to make two things:

1. When I click on a Widget, some contentScript executes and some data is returned to the add-on
2. This data should be shown in the Panel attached to the Widget.
3. If I click again, data must be updated and Panel content as well.

Here's what I have on Mozilla's sdk 1.15.

The "from widget" message is printed as expected, but the "from panel" one is not.

I have two questions:

1. If I want to show `foo` in my Panel, is this the correct way to do it? How do I update the panel with the info passed from the content script?
2. Why does my postMessage doesnt receive the message my Widget has sent?

   ```
   var widgets = require('sdk/widget');
   var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
   var self = require('sdk/self');
   var data = require('sdk/self').data;

   var requestsPanel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
       width:215,
       height:160,
       contentURL: data.url('requests.html'), //this is just dummy data
   });

   // try to receive data DOESN'T WORK
   requestsPanel.on('message', function (foo) {
       console.log('from panel', foo);
   });

   var widget = widgets.Widget({
       id: 'div-show',
       label: 'Show requests',
       contentURL: data.url('favicon.ico'),
       panel: requestsPanel,
       onClick: function() {
           worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
               contentScript: "self.port.on('getData', function () {"+
                                   "var foo = [1,2,3];"+
                                   "self.port.emit('sendData', foo);"+
                               "});"
           });
           // request to check for generated requests
           worker.port.emit('getData');

           // check the return from generated requests
           worker.port.on('sendData', function (foo){
               console.log('from widget', foo);
               requestsPanel.postMessage(foo);
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Panel's postMessage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#postMessage%28message%29) send a message to the `contentScript` of the panel. You do not have any content script in this code for the panel: as you said, `requests.html` is just dummy data. What you have to do, is remove the `requestsPanel.on('message')` from your code, and put the listener in the document loaded by the panel.

To be clear, your `requests.html` will looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>It's my panel</title>
        <script>
          addon.on('message', function(data){
            console.log(data)
          })
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this way you can easily update any DOM element of the document itself once you get data.
Notice that I used the object `addon`. As you can read from the documentation linked above, for "trusted content" (document that comes with your add-on, so from data folder), you don't need to add a content script, but you can use the document's script itself, and having the object `addon` to exchange messages. The `addon` object behaves like the `self` in the content script.

I would also suggest you to use `contentScriptFile` in your widget, instead of `contentScript`, especially if you want to submit to addons.mozilla.org.
And you should declare `worker`, otherwise will be a undeclared global variable – it's better nowadays having `"use strict"` at the beginning of our JS file, in order to have strict mode too.

Remember also that as soon as you write code for Firefox's add-on, you can take advantages of all the ES6 features are already implemented in the browser, like *destructuring assignment*, *let*, *const*, *arrows functions*, and so on.

So, for instance, instead of:

```
var self = require('sdk/self'); // this is useless also in the current code
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
```

You can have:

```
const { data } = require('sdk/self');
```

And instead of:

```
   worker.port.on('sendData', function (foo){
        console.log('from widget', foo);
        requestsPanel.postMessage(foo);
    });
```

You could have:

```
   worker.port.on('sendData', foo => {
        console.log('from widget', foo);
        requestsPanel.postMessage(foo);
    });
```

And if you remove the log, it will be simply:

```
   worker.port.on('sendData', foo => requestsPanel.postMessage(foo));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I still didn't have time to look at this problem on my side, but your answer is very clear. Thank you very much. I'll accept as soon as I do some quick testing on my side.